# Removing query results based on record in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a simple query to pull addresses from an Address table, there is an additional Demographic table that has a field called FieldName, which could have a possible value of "DoNotMail" which is more of a field label. There is another field in the same table called ValueString, which could have a associated value of DontMail which is the actual value for the field.

I have a case statement to pull from that demographics table only those related to the DoNotMail values. Maybe there is a better way to use this in the where clause instead?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      CASE WHEN CUSTOMV.FieldName = 'do_not_mail_options' Then CUSTOMV.ValueString Else Null END as DoNotMail,
                      IND.RecordNumber,  
                      ADDR.Line1, ADDR.Line2, ADDR.Line3,
                      ADDR.City, 
                     ADDR.StateName, 
                     AddressZipCode = ADDR.Zip,
                     AddressCountry = ADDR.CountryName, 
                     FirstName = Replace(IND.FirstName,',','-'), LastName = Replace(IND.LastName,',',''), AddressIsPreferredBilling = ADDR.IsPreferredBilling, 
                     ADDR.IsPreferredShipping
FROM            Crm.Individual IND WITH (NOLOCK) 
                     LEFT JOIN
                     Crm.CustomerAddress ADDR WITH (NOLOCK) ON IND.contactID = ADDR.ContactId AND ADDR.IsDeleted != '1' 
                     Left Join
                     crm.CustomFieldValue as CUSTOMV on CUSTOMV.ContactId = Ind.ContactId
WHERE       ADDR.IsPrimary = '1'
```

Results

```
+-----------+--------------+
| DoNotMail | RecordNumber |
+-----------+--------------+
| NULL      |     00000036 |
| NULL      |      9757035 |
| DontMail  |      9757035 |
+-----------+--------------+
```

When I link the two tables and pull addresses, what I get is 2 records for anyone who has DoNotMail. One record has Null for the DoNotMail field, the other record has "DontMail" for the DoNotMail field, otherwise the rest is duplicate. This should be just 1 record so I can sort and just delete them in excel. Or if possible ignore those donotmail folks straight out of the query.

Comment: how are you doing the JOIN?  use a '...LEFT JOIN on FieldName = 'do_not_mail' AND ID1 = ID2'  then your value will be NULL if there is not 'do not mail' and also you will get one join only

Comment: You expect help, but we don't see query.  How do you think we can help you?

Comment: I should clarify the FieldName field, so lets say i put in the where
    FieldName <> 'do_not_mail'
I would still get a record for a user that had do_not_mail. Becuase there are other demographic values for that FieldName field such as "department" for example.

Comment: Please, edit your question to add a sample data and the desired results.

Comment: Use `SELECT *` to see if those "same" records actually differ in some other fields.

Comment: Sorry about that folks, i meant to put in my query i only put in the Case at first. I have edited the original post to show the query now

Comment: I think what I am asking is if a query result can be filtered based on its own results. So in my results above since record 9757035  has a value other than Null, all 9757035 records should be ignored in the query result.

Comment: @Justin Do you mean a SubQuery/CTE? Your question is unclear, as I told you before you need to edit your question to include a sample data ans the desired results to get a proper answers.

Comment: @Sami Apologies I am making this difficult, its hard to give the full query result since its confidential data (addresses). So i am just using the PrimaryKey and the result of my Case Statement.

Actual Results: I get a list of all addresses, the Case statement shows me those who have a record in the Demographics table related to "Do_not_mail". As of right now, the results show duplicate addresses (2 rows) for those who have "do_not_mail"

Results Needed: I at least need the result for those with "Do_not_mail" to just be 1 row, so i can sort and delete them in excel.

Comment: And yes i think a Subquery is the answer, but I cant wrap my head around how to use it for this case. The way these tables are arranged are very confusing. Most normal people would have separate fields for flags like this. But instead its a single field that could mean 20 different fields. I will try to post an example of how this Demographic table works.

Comment: Below is the results from the demographics table for one of the users in the example above. Forgive me if its ugly, apparently its really hard to post table data here.

+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+

| ContactId |       FieldName       |   ValueString    |
+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+
|   9757035 | alwaysunchecked       | NULL             |
|   9757035 | bio                   | NULL             |
|   9757035 | department            | NULL             |
|   9757035 | do_not_mail_options   | Customer Opt-Out |

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to select `ValueString` for 'do_not_mail' then

```
  select ValueString from t where FieldName = 'do_not_mail';
```

Comment: Hi, yes i can do this just fine. But what i need to do is remove values based on that result from the larger query. So if value string = DontMail. or really if there is a row for do_not_mail at all, this entire record should be ignored from the main query

Comment: If you provide sample data and expected output you can get proper answer from us. This way we are only trying to guess what you really want

Comment: The current output is in the original post for 2 users. The expected output would be for user 9757035  to just have 1 row like this
| DontMail  |      9757035 |

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out my own solution, sorry for all the chaos everyone. I created a sub query for the where clause to pull only IDs that are NOT in the subquery below. Thank you all for your guidance, it is helpful to bounce ideas off of other.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                      IND.RecordNumber
FROM            Crm.Individual IND WITH (NOLOCK) 
                     Left Join
                     crm.CustomFieldValue as CUSTOMV on CUSTOMV.ContactId = Ind.ContactId
WHERE       
        CUSTOMV.FieldName = 'do_not_mail_options'
```